# Recommendation for books on boundary-value problems that include perturbed boundaries and many solved problems

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, online-resources

I am looking for a book or resource that contains applied math analytical methods and a lot of solved problems in Boundary-Value Problems for second-order PDEs, and if it could be related to wave-equation problems in 2D or 3D domains/structures, such as electromagnetics, it would be even better. I have found texts that have extensive treatment of perturbations (e.g. [Bender and Orzag](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387989315)), but they mainly focused on initial value problems, not perturbations of the boundary geometry itself. I also like the book by [Dudley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0780310225), but it doesn't have much solved problems with perturbations. The classic tomes by [Morse and Feshbach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000H6ERJM) are also great, but have very few solved problems that help one to practice more.

Ideally, something in the spirit of Schaum's outline series for solved problems would be perfect, but I couldn't find such a source yet for advanced boundary-value problems and/or perturbed boundaries. The aim is to practice more in this topic and develop my techniques in approximate analytical solutions for different boundary shapes and perturbations.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: [Non-Homogeneous Media and Vibratin Theory by Sanchez-Palencia](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-10000-8) has a number of examples,

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 worked examples:
Problems in PERTURBATION by Ali Hasan Nayfeh ISBN 0-471-82292-2, 15.36,15.41.
Here is another non worked problem:
Methods of Mathematical Physics, Jeffreys & Jeffreys, ISBN 0-521-09723-1.24.3.
Here is another method of approximation:
Calculus of Variations, Robert Weinstock, ISBN 0-486-63069-2.